What does the operator ?: do in a Ruby regular expression when placed immediately after a (, particularly when the regex contains groups?
string = "This is a paragraph with a bunch3c:77:e6:68:66:e9of random MAC addresses 1100:50:7F:E6:96:20hello world 15:00s, 00:50:56:c0:00:08 some other text is written here 00-0C-29-38-1D-61 00:11:22book.FF:DD:CC"
mac_regex = /(?:[0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5}[0-9A-F]{2}/i
mac_addresses = string.scan(mac_regex)
print mac_addresses 

This returns ["3c:77:e6:68:66:e9", "00:50:7F:E6:96:20", "00:50:56:c0:00:08", "00-0C-29-38-1D-61"].
If I remove ?: from mac_regex, so mac_regex = /([0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5}[0-9A-F]{2}/i, then print mac_addresses returns [["66:"], ["96:"], ["00:"], ["1D-"]], which means that ([0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5} only matches the fifth occurrence of an octet, instead of all five of them together (my understanding is that it is supposed to match all five of them together).
Why does ([0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5} correspond to matching the fifth octet, instead of a string of 5 octets? And why is ?: needed, ([0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5} -> (?:[0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5}, to make it correspond to matching a string of 5 octets?

Generally questions about regex expressions can be most easily answered by simply placing them into Regex101. In this case (?:): "Non-capturing group (?:)"

Unfortunate that this was closed since the question is also about the behavior of String#scan, which the linked question does not answer.

@Max ...but this does: Ruby regex multiple repeating captures. Either way, it's a dupe.

@InSync not really... it only mentions scan offhand in a negative voted answer.

@Max Not necessarily the method, but the behaviour.

(?:...) is a non-capturing group. This is being used because String#scan has two different behaviors:

if the regex has no capture groups, it outputs an array of matches
if the regex has capture groups, it outputs an array of arrays, where each array is the captured groups

Since that pattern has only one group, and it is non-capturing, scan uses the first behavior and returns just the complete matches as an array.
Removing the ?: means it switches to the second behavior and returns only that one group. And since the repetition {5} is outside of the group, that means the group only refers to each octet, not all five together; therefore the captured octet will be the last one matched.
To accomplish the same behavior without ?:, you need to add another capture group for the whole pattern and then extract that group from the result:
mac_regex = /(([0-9A-F]{2}[\:\-]){5}[0-9A-F]{2})/i
mac_addresses = string.scan(mac_regex).map(&:first)


It's perhaps worth mentioning that there are times when the regex contains contains capture groups but the first behaviour of scan you mention is desired. In those cases one can use the form of String#gsub that takes one argument and no block, returning an enumerator the generates matches of the regex...

... Suppose, for example, the string were str = "aabbbbcdefff" and it was desired to return matches of at least three consecutive identical letters, namely, "bbbb" and "fff". One could use the regex rgx = /(.)\1{2,}/ but str.scan(rgx) #=> [["b"], ["f"]], which we don't want, whereas arr.gsub(rgx).to_a #=> ["bbbb", "fff"], which is what we do want.
